# Is there an easy to set individual cell background color in the rally provided table API?

Tags: rally

As the title suggests, is there an easy way to set the color of a cell in the rally table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not via the component directly.  You could loop over the dom nodes the table generates and set the background-color style to the color you want.  Or, if you want to color a column or a row you could write a CSS3 selector to do it (if you're using a modern browser- not IE)